# Find the top 2 records for each key in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of results of player's scores in games, and I need to get the first two finishers for each game. LIMIT 2 works for the result set as a whole, but I need to limit it to 2 (or 1 if there is only one) per game.

Table being queried:

| game_id | player_id | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 1 | 20 | 300 |
| 1 | 30 | 200 |
| 2 | 40 | 100 |
| 2 | 50 | 200 |

Desired results:

| game_id | player_id | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 300 |
| 1 | 30 | 200 |
| 2 | 50 | 200 |
| 2 | 40 | 100 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RANK()` we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY game_id ORDER BY score DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT game_id, player_id, score
FROM cte
WHERE rnk <= 2
ORDER BY game_id, score DESC;
```

Note that if there be the possibility of ties, then you might want to use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `RANK`.  If ties are not a concern, then you could also use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK`.